# How to check whether test case has passed or failed and to know its index value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to check test cases' status such as whether it passed or failed, and know its index value.

How can I achieve this?

I tried binary search. Here is the code:

```
class Array
  def binary_search(val, low = 0, high = length - 1)
    return nil if high < low
    mid = (low + high) >> 1
    case val <=> self[mid]
    when -1
      binary_search(val, low, mid - 1)
    when 1
      binary_search(val, mid + 1, high)
    else
      mid
    end
  end
end

ary = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 26, 45, 67, 78, 90]
[0, 42, 45, 24324, 99999].each do |val|
  i = ary.binary_search(val)
  if i
    puts "found #{val} at index #{i}: #{ary[i]}"
  else
    puts "#{val} not found in array"
  end
end
```

But that is for whether a key is found or not.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is a test case and index have to do. Different terminologies

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider the following.

```
ary = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 26, 45, 67, 78, 90]
a = [0, 42, 45, 24324, 99999]

h = ary.each_with_index.to_h
  #=> {0=>0, 1=>1, 4=>2, 5=>3, 6=>4, 7=>5, 8=>6, 9=>7, 12=>8, 26=>9,
  #    45=>10, 67=>11, 78=>12, 90=>13}

a.each do |val|
   i = h[val]
   puts i ? "found #{val} at index #{i}: #{ary[i]}" : "#{val} not found in array"
end
found 0 at index 0: 0
42 not found in array
found 45 at index 10: 45
24324 not found in array
99999 not found in array
```

The use of the hash permits fast lookups of keys and in `h` matching values in `a`.

Comment: I want to check test cases has been passed or failed how can i achieve this

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know how to test your code using, for example, [rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec)? In any event, your need to clarify your question with an edit.

Comment: ok i'l explain the scenario,,for instance between 1 to 10 test cases first test case has been passed and 10th has been failed i need to check from which test case it has been failing let us consider it got failed at 5th then it is not needed to check below it , i need to check above it,,,kindly help me to solve this scenario

Comment: i have tried with below code now i want to check if the 50th test cases has been failed means i need to check  above test cases, how can this be done                                                                                                 test= Array.new(100)                                                                                      
test [1]=['pass']

test [50] ='pass'
puts test [2]
puts test[4]
puts count= test.size
puts count1=test.size/2.0
puts test[50]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You often refer to a "test case" but nowhere explain what that is. Is it refer to a single element of your array `ary` or `[0, 42, 45, 24324, 99999]`?

Comment: test case refers to a hash consisting of key and value

Comment: What hashes? You don't refer to any hashes in the question.

Comment: sorry my test case refers to the list of array eg:list[0]='false'